# How do I check boxes in a collection for existing records in simple form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Say I have an input field like this:

```
<%= f.input :parents, collection: @nodes, as: :check_boxes, label: "Parents" %>
```

What I would like to happen is for any `@nodes` that are already `node.parents` of the existing node, rather than showing their checkbox as empty, I would like it to have a checkbox in it.

The idea being that I should be able to uncheck them and check others to change the parents of the existing node.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, please include some more code and maybe the relevant parts of your `Node` or `FamilyTree` models to show the associations.

Comment: @smathy I edited the question so that it can be more clear. Don't be distracted by the `FamilyTree` or `Node` model. Basically, 1 `@node` can have multiple parents in the form of other `@nodes` or `@node.parents`. So when we are loading the form that allows the user to set the parents, how do we check the boxes for the parents that currently exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use a [checkbox collection builder](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes). It let's you add logic for each checkbox rendered, so you would just need a simple model function for checking parents. Something like this:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:node, :node_ids, @nodes, :id, :node_name) do |b| %>
  <% isParent = true %>
  <%= b.label { b.check_box(checked:isParent) } %>
<%end%>
```

EDIT - with simple_form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @node do |f| %>
 <%=  f.input :parents,
        :collection => @nodes,
        :as => :check_boxes,
        :checked => @node.parent_ids #array of node ids for parents
 %>
<% end %>
```

Then retrieve an array of parent node ids with a model function.

Comment: The issue is I am using simple_form to manage my form. How do I use the checkbox collection builder with simple_form?

Comment: Ahh...that's cool. So in my case, it would be something like: `checked: @node.parents` right? I tried that and it doesn't work. I even tried `checked: [@node.parents]`.

Comment: Something like that... I'm not sure what your `nodes.rb` looks like

Comment: Ahh...I got it, it should actually be the IDs of the node. So what worked was `checked: @node.parent_ids`. Thanks much.